Power supply watt calculation
I have a laptop power supply with the following info:
Input: 100-240V~1.5A 50-60Hz
And my country's power line is 220V. So now what are the watt calculations and the used amps? What if this laptop is used in a country with 120V?

P=IV, Power in watt=220x1.5=330W.

@liaifat85 and if countries with 120v it would be 120x1.5=180W? That doesn't make sense!


what are the Watt calculations and the used Amps

It depends on what load power is connected to the output. You can assume the power supply is about 85% efficient so, if the load power is (say) 50 watts then the input power will be getting close to 60 watts.
The ampere figures marked on the power supply (1.5 amps) are worst case i.e. at the lowest supply voltage and, may be subject to a power factor that is significantly less than unity. Hence the marked numbers do not allow you to conclude anything about input power into the supply.
To reiterate: you need to know the output load power.

What if this laptop is used in a country with 120V

The input current will be about 80% higher than the current taken at 220 volts but, this assumes a decent power output taken from the supply.

So can I assume the 1.5A is for 100V and the power is 150 watts? I'm trying to calculate this for buying a proper UPS.

No, you can't assume that. The 1.5 amps will be taken when the connected load is at its rated full value and, your question does not indicate what this is. It might only draw 50 mA when disconnected from a load. @Amir
